# 【Python3】Beautiful Soupについての質問

Tags: python

Beautiful Soupで

```
<div class="hoge1">
 <div class="hoge2">
  <p>hogehoge</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

といったHTMLコードから`<p>`の部分を取得するにはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 単純に全ての`<p>`を取得したいのか、`class="hoge2"`内の`<p>`を取得したいのか、`<p>`は複数あるのか等の詳細がないと本来欲しい回答は得られないと思いますよ。

Answer (score 1):

下記ではいかがでしょうか。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
    <div class="hoge1">
     <div class="hoge2">
      <p>hogehoge1</p>
      <p>hogehoge2</p>
     </div>
    </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
text1 = soup.find_all("p")  # htmlからpのタグを取得 配列で出力
text2 = text1[0].string  # 取得した配列データからタグの文字列を取得
text3 = text1[1].string  # 取得した配列データからタグの文字列を取得

print(text1)
print(text2)
print(text3)

>> > [ < p > hogehoge1 < /p > , < p > hogehoge2 < /p > ]
>> > hogehoge1
>> > hogehoge2
```